# Can you use static constants inside classes in PHP?

Tags: php, class, variables, syntax, constants

I expected the following to work but it doesn't seem to.

```
<?php

class Patterns
{
    public static const EMAIL = "/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix";
    public static const INT = "/^\d+$/";
    public static const USERNAME = "/^\w+$/";
}
```

Because it throws this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_CONST, expecting T_VARIABLE
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can use const in class like this:

```
class Patterns {
    const EMAIL = "/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix";
    const INT = "/^\d+$/";
    const USERNAME = "/^\w+$/";
}
```

And can access `USERNAME` const like this:

```
Patterns::USERNAME
```

Comment: When its a const, it should be handled as static internally by the PHP compiler I believe since its value cant be changed.

Comment: but values of `static variables` can be changed by the way these are handled as like `static` because they can't be changed implicitly but can change if it depends on a global variable and the `global variable` changes before the `instance` of `class` is created

Comment: Wouldn't this method create copies of the constants for each new instance or am I wrong? Is it possible to create class constants that refer to a single static reference or is this just not possible in php?

Comment: From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php): "Note that class constants are allocated once per class, and not for each class instance."

Answer (score 38):

In PHP, static and const are two different things.

const denotes a class constant.  They're different than normal variables as they don't have the '$' in front of them, and can't have any visibility modifiers (public, protected, private) before them.  Their syntax:

```
class Test
{
    const INT = "/^\d+$/";
}
```

Because they're constant, they're immutable.

Static denotes data that is shared between objects of the same class.  This data *can* be modified.  An example would be a class that keeps track of how many instances are in play at any one time:

```
class HowMany
{
    private static $count = 0;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$count++;
    }

    public function getCount()
    {
        return self::$count;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        self::$count--;
    }
}

$obj1 = new HowMany();
$obj2 = new HowMany();

echo $obj1->getCount();

unset($obj2);

echo $obj1->getCount();
```

Comment: As of PHP 7.1.0  [class constants can have visibility modifiers](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#language.oop5.basic.class.this).

Answer (score 11):

They're not static constants, just constants

```
class Patterns 
{ 
    const EMAIL = "/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix"; 
    const INT = "/^\d+$/"; 
    const USERNAME = "/^\w+$/"; 
} 

echo Patterns::EMAIL;
```

Answer (score 8):

Nope class constants can't be labeled static nor assigned visibility.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: What's the best alternative in you opinion. If you have to write the example class in a way that acceptable in PHP - how would you do it? Thanks!

Comment: @Emanuil: then he would remove "public" and "static" keywords ;-)

Comment: @Sarfraz: I want to have a class that holds a collection of commonly used regular expressions that all my apps can use.

Comment: @Emanuil: Then you should create a public associative array variable to hold those regex.

Comment: @Sarfraz - It loks as though somebody systematically downvoted almost every answer here about 3 hours ago

Comment: btw as of PHP7.1 constants can get visibility -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare them static or public. Check out the examples in the manual:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to access the constants?

I believe this would work:

```
echo Patterns::$EMAIL; //shows "/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-...."
```

If you just declare it as static.

Comment: it is not a constant in your sample, but a static variable.

Comment: @zerkms which is why I said if you just declare it as static 

@mattbasta is that not what he wanted?

Comment: you can see what he wanted at the checked answer.