# Use a static function to define an array for the choices options of a form

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I use the easyAdminBundle, I would like to know if it's possible to use a `static function` or `const` (define anywhere in my app) to set the `choices` option of a `choice` type as such :

```
- { property: tag, type: choice, type_options: { choices: 'App\Entity\News::getTags' }
```

With a `getTags` function like :

```php
class News 
{
    const TAGS = ['toto','tutu'];

    static public function getTags()
    {
        return $this::TAGS;
    }
}
```

It is already possible to do that with `query_builder` but I didn't find any trace of it in the documentation.

Actually I get the following error which lead me to think it's not possible (but maybe someone here do):

> An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType": The option "choices" with value "App\Entity\News::getTags" is expected to be of type "null" or "array" or "\Traversable", but is of type "string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice of [@David Alvarez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9478327/david-alvarez), I've tried to access the `const` property directly from the yaml file. This is possible thanks to this [symfony update](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files) available since the 3.2 version.

so to access a const property as :

```php
class News 
{
    const TAGS = ['toto' => 'toto','tutu' => 'tutu'];
}
```

I'll write :

```
{ choices: !php/const App\Entity\News::TAGS }
```

and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set `const TAGS` to static and inside of `getTags()`,
replace `$this` by `self`.

AND

```php
{ choices: App\Entity\News::getTags() }
```

Remove the apostrophes and add () to actually call the function

Comment: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389380/can-you-use-static-constants-in-php) (and my compiler) you cannot set `static const` in php. anyways that's the reason of the `static function`. I replaced the `$this` with `self` as suggested and the `()`to the call in the yaml file. I still got the same error. As if it was not interpreted as a function....

Comment: I’m not 100% of that but if you use an attribute which is not static you have to create an instance of News to access it. But here you access News statically

Comment: `const`are accecible statically. but just to make sure I've tried with a `static private $TAGS` and I still get the same error

Comment: Try to directly access the constant instead of using a function : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685922/php-5-const-vs-static#1685933

Comment: I am almost sure that the error telle you that you give a string because you put the apostrophes, which is a string. What error do you have when removing apostrophes ?

Comment: the same, but following your advice I'v been to the [symfony website](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files) and find a way to access directly the constants from yaml. works like a charm. I'm posting an answer